# Debian iptables

Tags: debian, iptables, port-forwarding

For quite some time I was trying to forward ports or/and connect between 2 devices inside VPN and I couldn't figure it out.
I have VPS setup on Debian 9.0 x64 with ExternalIP.
I created VPN based on hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn from github. It's installed, and all work just fine. I can connect to server via VPN and my IP address change to ExternalIP.

Now the problem is, I want to go other way.

IncommingIP -> (eth0) ExternalIP -forwarded to-> (pppX) VPNIP

My currnet iptables look like this:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Jun 29 10:55:31 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [21617:1100891]
:INPUT ACCEPT [17101:829091]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [703:55681]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [703:55681]
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 8.8.8.8
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 8.8.8.8
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.42.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

#-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.42.10:8080
#-A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.42.10 -o ppp0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.42.1
-A PREROUTING --src 0/0 --dst 192.168.42.10 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080


COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jun 29 10:55:31 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Jun 29 10:55:31 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [16:676]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [221:33480]
:f2b-sshd - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -m policy --dir in --pol none -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 500,4500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -j DROP
```

There is some leftover after my tries to PRE/POST Routing that are not working.

What I should change to make it work as forwarding let's say port 8080 for test?
Also why can't I connect inside the VPN network? (only ping is working)
And what the hell is that numbers in bracket? `:PREROUTING ACCEPT [21617:1100891]`

Please help

Comment: Add a complete example with protocol, source IP and target both IP and port and to which values you want them changed.

Comment: Well I want to forward port 8080 from eth0 (1.2.3.4) to ppp0 (192.168.42.10). If it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your NAT rules are incorrect. Try the following (assuming you have just freshly installed IPSec/VPN server)

To view existing NAT chain rules (before deletion):

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -L -n --line-numbers
```

To delete existing NAT rules:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 3
```

Repeat above command until you are left with following two NAT rules:

```
1    MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.42.0/24      0.0.0.0/0
2    MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.43.0/24      0.0.0.0/0            policy match dir out pol none
```

Now its time to add your DNAT rule, that will forward `TCP 8080` from internet IP (`1.2.3.4`)  to VPN client IP (`192.168.42.10`)

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.42.10:8080
```

Thats all you need. You can then save the iptables rules if all working is fine.